# ToggleButton state was reset to previous when I am scrolling the listview

Tags: android, android-listview, togglebutton

I am using ToggleButtons in a listview, and I set the state of togglebutton from the webservice data, now I changed the state of togglebutton, but it is reset to previous when I scrolling the listview.

I used the following in my adapter class.

```
tbtnStatus=(ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.togglebtn);
tbtnStatus.setTag(new Integer(position));  

tbtnStatus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);


tbtnStatus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String update_status;
        String current_status=buttonView.getText().toString();
         if(current_status.equals("ON"))
         {
             update_status="NO";
         }

         else
         {
             update_status="YES";
         }

        String res=UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl(DataUrls.updateindividualstaus+"?pilotid="+DataUrls.pilotid+"&friendid="+friendid[position]+"&status="+update_status);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

State of your toggle button will be cleared to it's default value from webservice data each time when you sroll it out of the screen, because views of all not currently visible rows are deleted and will be recreated with default values. You need to save state of you toggle button. For example, you can save it in object associated with this row if you use `ArrayAdapter<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

save your position of View when u check the toggle button of that respective view...and in getView() write this code

```
    if(yourposition==position)
    tbtnStatus.setChecked(true);
```

Suppose you clicked 3rd position toggle..save 3 as yourposition and  when u will scroll  getView gets called and will satify the condition checking your toggle to yes